# Basic ocaml program not compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

I was trying to write a piece of code that checks if a sentence is a palindrome (if we don't consider spaces and case) but my code won't compile. I get the following error :

```
File "main.ml", line 12, characters 0-2:
Error: Syntax error
```

This error corresponds to the second program, line 12 being where the ;; are at.

Entire program

```ml
let scan_word () = Scanf.scanf " %s" (fun x -> x)
in
let scan_int () = Scanf.scanf " %d" (fun x -> x)
in
let scan_float () = Scanf.scanf " %f" (fun x -> x)
in
let scan_char () = Scanf.scanf " %c" (fun x -> x)
in
let maj_to_min = function
    | c when (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') -> c
    | c -> (char_of_int ( (int_of_char c) - (int_of_char 'A') + (int_of_char 'a')))
in

let convert_string s = 
    let n = String.length s in
    let cur = ref 0 in
    let arr = Array.make n ' ';
    for i = 0 to (n-1)
    do
        if s.[i] <> ' ' 
        then begin
            arr.(!cur) <- maj_to_min s.[i];
            incr cur;
        end;
    done;
    (Array.sub arr 0 cur)
in

let is_palindrome arr =
    let n = Array.length arr in
    let ans = ref true in

    for i = 0 to (n-1)
    do
        ans := (!ans) && (arr.(i) = arr.(n-1-i));
    done;
    !ans
in

let n = read_int () in

for i = 1 to n
do
    let s = read_line () in 
    if (is_palindrome (convert_string s)) = true  then print_endline s
done;;
```

Minimal program which doesn't compile :

```ml
let scan_word () = Scanf.scanf " %s" (fun x -> x)
in
let scan_int () = Scanf.scanf " %d" (fun x -> x)
in
let scan_float () = Scanf.scanf " %f" (fun x -> x)
in
let scan_char () = Scanf.scanf " %c" (fun x -> x)
in
let maj_to_min = function
    | c when (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') -> c
    | c -> (char_of_int ( (int_of_char c) - (int_of_char 'A') + (int_of_char 'a')))
;;
```

The maj_to_min converts upper case letts to lower-case letters.
I'd like to understand where did I make a mistake when writing code ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `let ... in` is an expression, not a top level declaration. Remove all the `in`s, then it'll compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't compile because your code is not a syntactically valid OCaml.

An OCaml program is a sequence of value, type, module, and other *definitions*. Your particular example is trying to define several values. A value definition in OCaml is having the following syntax

```
let <name> = <value>
```

Note, that there is no `in` part.  So the correct (syntactically at least) program would look like this

```
let scan_word () = Scanf.scanf " %s" (fun x -> x)
let scan_int () = Scanf.scanf " %d" (fun x -> x)
let scan_float () = Scanf.scanf " %f" (fun x -> x)
let scan_char () = Scanf.scanf " %c" (fun x -> x)
let maj_to_min = function
    | c when (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') -> c
    | c -> (char_of_int ( (int_of_char c) - (int_of_char 'A') + (int_of_char 'a')))
```

This program will define 5 functions. Neither will be called, so you would probably like to add a definition that will call it.

The main difference between `let <name> = <expr-1> in <expr-2>` and `let <name> = <expr>` is that the latter is the value definition which occurs on the program/module top-level. It is the closest to the what is named statement in other languages. The former, I mean the `let <name> = <expr-1> in <expr-2>` is an expression, which can occur in any place where an expression is expected. And usually it is used to build complex expressions. e.g.,

```
let input_user () = 
    let name = scan_word () in
    let age = scan_int () in
    let weight = scan_float () in
    let gender = scan_char () in
    printf "%s is %d years old, weights %g pounds, and has gender %c\n"
       name age weight gender
```

and now to make your binary do something you can call this function, add the following value definition to the top-level of your program, e.g.,

```
   let () = input_user ()
```

This will serve as an entry point of your program.

To elaborate a little more, this is a general structure of an OCaml program:

```
(* this is the top-level of your file, each file defines a module 
   which has the name equal to the file name (but capitalized), 
   let's imagine that our file is named example.ml therefore it 
   defines a module named Example
 *)


(* this is a top-level constant that is visible to all code that is below 
    it. You can also access it from other files as `Example.version`.
 *)
let version = "0.0.1"


(* this is a mutable reference, the closest to the mutable and global 
   variable in C *)
let calls = ref 0

(* this is a simple function with two imperative expressions, which uses 
   values defined above *)
let make_a_call () = 
    incr calls;
    Printf.printf "we made %d calls so far in version %s\n" !calls version


(* this is a function, that defines local variables `d` and `e` and
   uses them. These variables are seen only in the body of this 
   function. More generally `let <v> = <e> in <body>` evaluates `<e>`
   binds it to `<v>` and makes `<v>` visible in the scope of `<body>` *)
let complex_function x y = 
   let d = x + y - 1 in
   let e = x * y + 2 in
   (d + e) / (x + y)


(* we can even define function inside other functions, the 
   same as with `d` and `e` above, the `inner_function` is only 
   visible inside the `complex_function_with_functions` *)
let complex_function_with_functions x = 
   let inner_function y = 
      x + y in
   inner_function 5 + inner_function 6 


(* this is the main function. The name doesn't matter at all, well at
   least to OCaml. But it is usually a good idea to have one at least
   to cherish others who will be reading your code. This function
   demonstrates how you can interleave imperative expressions with
   `let` bindings` *)
let main () = 
   make_a_call ();
   let r = complex_function_with_functions 12 in
   make_a_call ();
   let p = complex_function r 16 in 
   make_a_call ();
   Printf.printf "wow: we get %d and %d, don't know what it means\n" r p


(* finally, let's call the main function to actually run our program *)

let () = main ()
```

A pro tip, you don't really need to compile this file to run it, as OCaml has an interpreter, so if you put this code in the file named `example.ml` then it is as easy as,

```
$ ocaml example.ml 
we made 1 calls so far in version 0.0.1
we made 2 calls so far in version 0.0.1
we made 3 calls so far in version 0.0.1
wow: we get 35 and 12, don't know what it means
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining ! So to be clear, all of the constant variables (so functions as well) I want to use later in my main code should be written without in, but then in my main code (so the part that would be in main() in C for example), I need to put "in" after each declaration ?

Comment: not really, it is more about the scope, I've updated the answer with a simple example, that will (I hope) clarify the difference.