# A syntax error when trying to define an inner function

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I have this function

```
let rec g (a:float) (b:int) : int = 
let rec func (x:float*char) (y:int) : float = 
   let (v,w) = x in
  let w' = int_of_char w in
  (func (float_of_int y, w) (g v w')) +. 2.1
```

I know there is a problem that is unable to stop the recursion at certain condition.(the compiler will prompt stack overflow error). But I got a syntax error in compiling this, I think types are correct and I add rec in front of function names, still not work. what's wrong?

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: The definition of `g` is missing

Comment: I has function g at the beginning, and then I call this. Why it is missing?

Comment: `let rec g (a:float) (b:int) : int = ` isn't a valid function definition. It's missing its body, the part that actually does stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will indent your code with some auto-indentation tool (a highly recommended practice), then the problem with your code will become obvious, e.g., this is how your code looks like after going through [ocp-indent](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ocp-indent/):

```
let rec g (a:float) (b:int) : int = 
  let rec func (x:float*char) (y:int) : float = 
    let (v,w) = x in
    let w' = int_of_char w in
    (func (float_of_int y, w) (g v w')) +. 2.1
```

So, as you may see, the `let rec func ...` expression is unfinished, it has to have the `in` part, but it doesn't. Here is a simple template for writing functions that have functions inside them,

```
let <outer-function-name> <outer-args> =
   let <inner-function-name> <inner-args> = 
       <inner-function-body> in
   <outer-function-body>
```

Substitute parts delimited with `<` and `>` with your code and you will get everything working.

Most likely, the crux of the problem is that you're confusing the following two syntactic constructs:

```
let <var> = <exp>
```

and

```
let <var> = <exp> in <body>
```

They are commonly confused, that's not surprising given how similar they look. However, they are very different. The former is a *definition*<sup>1</sup> while the latter is an *expression*. The former may occur only on the top-level of a module while the latter may occur in any place where an expression is expected. I know it could be confusing, so you probably could benefit from reading my other answer, where I give a few [simple examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416685/2625442) of how things are done in OCaml.

---

<sup>1)</sup>)The thing that is closest to what is named *statement* in some other languages

Comment: I find it easier to read with the `in` in a separate line for any multi-line `let`

Comment: I personally find it ugly and a usual indicator of a code that smells :) A code that is hard to read without having to put `in` on a separate line just requires refactoring.